# Spring Rest servcie prodouces JSON but not for objects mapped with a db

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

It took me hours to realize, what the problem is:

I have a Spring Rest service and a GET-Method which returns a user in JSON-Format. 
The data comes from my database over sessionFactory.

After debugging it turned out, that the Problem is related to my bidrectional onetomany-manytoone relationship.

So calling

```
        User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, userId);
```

returns a User-Object where user.getCity().getSupplier() runs into an com.sun.jdi.InvocationException. Therefore Jackson is obviously unable to serialize.
But what causes this exception?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CITY")
public class City implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Supplier> supplier;
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public User() {
}

@Id
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private City city;
```

Supplier:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_SUPPLIER")
public class Supplier implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private City city;
```

Comment: If you turn your logs to DEBUG you should see what happens server side. Are you using an ORM framework? Is the `getUser` method returning a lazy loaded entity?

Comment: Please show the source code for User class

Comment: Have you got a reverse mapping to user in City?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, I think you'll find that your issues are related to the x-to-x relationships. This can sometimes create circular reference issues when trying to jsonify the entity beans.

Sometimes you can avoid or get past this by using annotations, other times a wrapper class is needed. I often just write a wrapper class to handle my JSON transactionts

There are many many references to this type of issues spanning many languages. Here a few starting points for you to research.

- [Google related search regarding circular references in entity objects](https://www.google.com/search?q=openjdk+vs+sun+jdk&oq=open+jdk+vs+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.3090j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=json%20entity%20circular%20reference)
- [Json and Java - Circular Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393812/json-and-java-circular-reference)
- [Circular Dependencies With Jackson](http://java.dzone.com/articles/circular-dependencies-jackson)