# JPARepository findAll() loop data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 3 entities:

```
SLUSER_INFO(SLUSER_INFO_ID, FULLNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, DOB)
SLUSER(SLUSER_ID, PASSWORD, USERNAME, SLUSER_INFO_ID)
SLROLE(SLROLE_ID, ROLENAME, SLUSER_ID)
```

In User entity:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 @JsonView(SlUserView.Full.class)
 private List<SlRole> roles;

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "SLUSER_INFO_ID", referencedColumnName = "SLUSER_INFO_ID")
 @JsonView(SlUserView.Full.class)
 private SlUserInfo  userInfo;
```

In Role entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SLUSER_ID", referencedColumnName = "SLUSER_ID")
private SlUser user;
```

and User_info entity

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userInfo")
private SlUser user;
```

I create the rest api to get all user by using JPARepository findAll

```
@Repository
public interface SlUserRepository extends JpaRepository<SlUser, Long> {

}
```

Controller

```
  public ResponseEntity<Page<SlUser>> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<SlUser> pageResult = usersRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return new ResponseEntity<Page<SlUser>>(pageResult, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

try to run the rest api, the results are duplicated data.

{"content":[{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":{"id":1,"username":"v7001","password":"admin","roles":[{"id":1,"roleName":"ADMIN"}],"userInfo":{"id":1,"fullName":"","firstName":"Jayce","lastName":"Sonar","address":"ad1","dob":null,"user":

Please give me advise

Comment: Probably just circular reference problem http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion or https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393856/1032167

Comment: The error is because of the bidirectionaly relationship between `User` and `Roles`. Use `@JsonIgnore` on `roles` in `User` entity.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan: thanks, it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of the bi-directional relationship between `User` and `Roles`.

Use `@JsonIgnore` on `roles` in `User` entity.