# Jackson in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, jackson

I have two entities with bidirectional relation

```
entity A {
   String name;
   Entity B b;
}

entity B {
   String name;
   int num;
   Entity A a;
}
```

with JsonManagedReference annotation, the serialized entity A will be

```
{ 
   name: xx,
   b: {
       name: yy,
       num: 1
      }
}
```

I'd like the entity A be serialized as

```
{ 
   name: xx,
   b: {
       name: yy,
       num: 1,
       a: xx
      }
}
```

or

```
{ 
   name: xx,
   b: {
       name: yy,
       num: 1,
       a: {name:xx}
      }
}
```

Which annotation should I use?

Comment: That's a circular reference problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393812/json-and-java-circular-reference