# Adding movie to one client rented movies list through API, will mess up all other clients

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I'm building this movie rental app and client has list called rentedMovies. If use PUT its gives me 200 code and everything seems fine, but if I reload my clients, its all messed up.
If I use JasonIgnore, it's okay but how could see then what movies have client rented...

Here is the list
[image]

Logic in service

[image]

Output in browser

[image]

Console output
[image]

Movie class
[image]

Comment: looks like you might a nested structure, can you add the Movie class and the table details if possible.

Comment: Uploaded pic of a class. Still can’t figure out the problem. Tried to rewrite the code but still faulty,  my knowledge is the problem :D

Comment: does your Client class refer to Movie ? Can you enable JSONIgnore for clients property and check ?

Comment: If I enable JsonIgnore it works, but is there a way to do it without using that annotation?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393812/json-and-java-circular-reference helps you out.