# How to break a cyclic relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwqqr.png)
table schemas
There are two tables, they can be seen in the diagram.
There is also a JPA-style description of these entities:

Entity for Gift

```
@Entity
public class Gift {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    // ... 

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "gift")
    private List<Image> images;
}
```

Entity fot Image

```
@Entity
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gift_id")
    private Gift gift;
    
    // ...

}
```

When executing the following JPA Query:

```
@Override
public List<Gift> getByFilter(FilterSearch filter) {
    String sql = """
            FROM Gift WHERE id = 2
            """;
    return entityManager.createQuery(sql, Gift.class).getResultList();
}
```

Result:
It turns out a cyclic dependency, if you can call it that: I get a list gift, in which image, in which the same gift has the same images, which in turn have the same gift's, and so on ad infinitum.

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "title for gift",
        "description": "some simple description for gift",
        "shortDescription": "short description",
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "first category",
            "parent": null
        },
        "costPrice": 2.0,
        "price": 3.4,
        "dateAdded": "2023-06-26T15:41:55.958+00:00",
        "isEnabled": false,
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "gift": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "title for gift",
                    "description": "some simple description for gift",
                    "shortDescription": "short description",
                    "category": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "first category",
                        "parent": null
                    },
                    "costPrice": 2.0,
                    "price": 3.4,
                    "dateAdded": "2023-06-26T15:41:55.958+00:00",
                    "isEnabled": false,
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": 6,
                            "gift": {
                                "id": 2,
                                "title": "title for gift",
                                "description": "some simple description for gift",
                                "shortDescription": "short description",
                                "category": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "first category",
                                    "parent": null
                                },
                                "costPrice": 2.0,
                                "price": 3.4,
                                "dateAdded": "2023-06-26T15:41:55.958+00:00",
                                "isEnabled": false,
                                "images": [
```

and so on ad infinitum.

**Question. How to break this cycle?**

Comment: Its perfectly fine for Java objects to point to each other, and hibernate uses that when reading the object from the database. An infinite recursion only occurs during serialization to JSON, and can be prevented by configuring your JSON library appropriately (since you haven't told us which library it's hard to be more specific than that ...)

Comment: @meriton Json Jackson.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393812/json-and-java-circular-reference